# Using a variable in req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How would I use a variable in `req.body`

example:

```
var names = {abc,xyz,cde};

var check = req.body.names[0];
```

OR

```
var names = {abc,xyz,cde};

var dummy = names[0];

var check = req.body.[dummy];
```

The first case throws an error that it `cannot read index 0` and the second gives an error of an `unexpected token '['`. I am simply trying to fetch form data who's names are stored in the array names.

PS: I am using Node in the back end.

Comment: The first should be `req.body[names[0]]`, the second should be `req.body[dummy]`

Comment: `body.[dummy]` is invalid syntax, should be `body[dummy]` (that's for the `unexpected token '['`). `names[0]` is invalid too, as `names` is an object, not an array.

Comment: ChrisG,Jeremy Thille thank you for your answers, that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use numeric indexes then `names` must be an array. Then use bracket notation:

```
var names = [abc, xyz, cde];
var check = req.body[names[0]];
```

Comment: `var names = [abc,xyz,cde]` ---> `Uncaught ReferenceError: abc is not defined`

Comment: @JeremyThille Obviously you need to defined those variables if you use then. If it's just static strings then `['abc', 'xyz', 'cde']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach stuff to the body as with any other object :

```
req.body.names = {key : "val"}

console.log( req.body.names.key ) // "val"
```